# Expose Custom Control Event that is defined in the Control Template of another Custom Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What I am looking to do is expose the click event of a button that is contained in a custom control. The instance of this custom control is declared in the control template of another custom control.

For example, say I have the following:

```
public class CustomTabPanel : Panel
{
    public Button newButton;
    //lots of other stuff
}
```

And then I have another control like so

```
public class CustomControl : Selector
{
    //stuff here
}
```

This CustomControl class has a template defined in generic.xaml that defines an instance of CustomTabPanel like so (stuff has been stripped out)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                    <local:CustomTabPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

An instance of this control can then be created in MainWindow.xaml or wherever.

My Question is, how can I access the Click event of the Button in CustomTabPanel in MainWindow.xaml assuming the control is defined there?

I’ve tried to keep this explanation as simple as possible, if you need any more implementation details please ask.

Many thanks for any help!

Kris

Answer (score 0):

Expose it as a dependency property on the CustomControl.
Wire it up in your CustomControl code file. It's kinda leveraging it.